# Does having a BIOS Password effect installation

Tags: preinstallation

So I'm currently running Windows 10 and I have a BIOS password set, now I want to switch to Ubuntu as my main OS. Now the question I have will my having the BIOS password affect the installation of Ubuntu in any way?

Comment: No. I don't see any reason that it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu installer does not make any changes to the BIOS settings when installing Ubuntu. Having a BIOS password will not affect the installation of Ubuntu in any way. The purpose of having a BIOS password is to limit access to the BIOS setup utility only to those users who have input the correct password.